# Stackoverflow full dataset for a month

Tags: sql

I found that their avaliable only a process to make queries to db to take the open source dataset of stackoverflow.

I found this nice [example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59301/questions-per-month-top-10-tags-compared#resultSets)

Is there any query I could use to take a full snippet from every variable avaliable for a month?

Comment: This really belongs on [meta], but before you go there (or it gets migrated, which may happen soon), you should probably clear up what you're looking for. Yes, the Stack Exchange Data Explorer is a very cool tool and you can run queries with it, but your question isn't super clear. What "variables" would you like to take snippets from? It might help to give an example of the type of data you'd like to have come back.

Comment: @Mathew Haugen. I though it was stackoverflow. When I say variables I mean the different tags, questions and answers, votes.

Comment: If you're asking about something general about T-SQL syntax, you should ask here. If you're asking about how to write something that depends on the SEDE schema, you should either ask on [meta] or include sufficient details about the tables and columns such that someone without knowledge of it wouldn't have to look into it.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: if belongs there why haven't you voted to move it to meta?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Migrations should only occur when a question is on-topic for the target site. Admittedly that rule is less relevant between meta and main sites, but I consider this question unclear in its current state, so I didn't consider moving it to meta to be the most effective way to use my vote.